# Transition only on the y value of a line point?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have created a line chart with D3.js that displays time-based series of values. The chart can be panned and zoomed. To improve the user experience, I also implemented auto-scaling on the Y-axis, which sets the domain of the y-axis to the values [min, max] extent of the currently visible data.

Now I want to add a transition to the chart that animates the change of the y-axis scale ([like in this example](http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/7030f35b72de721622b8)). It works, but unfortunately it looks and behaves terrible when panning the chart, because the transition does not only animate the y-part of each line point, but also the x-part, which leads to a very unpleasant effect of smearing the line horizontally as well as a noticable lag while panning the chart. It just feels wrong.

So what I would like to achieve is this: the x-property of the line's data should be set instantly without transition to avoid the lag, the y-property should be animated. This is the part where I update the chart:

```
self.svg.select("path.line").transition().attr("d", self.valueline);
```

Where `valueline` looks like this:

```
self.valueline = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function (d) { return self.x(d.t); })
  .y(function (d) { return self.y(d.v); });
```

Is there a way to apply the transition to `d.v` (the value) only?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, the way it's done in the example is not very idiomatic, it may be better to bind the data to the path first and then apply the transition.

Then you could bind some null data at the start with all `d.v == 0` and then bind the real data with a transition.  This gives a y-value-only transition.  [The following edits in the example](http://bl.ocks.org/cool-Blue/446b1e5a71ad04646a14) will show what I mean...

```
// Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
  var margin = {top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50},
    width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

  // Parse the date / time
  var parseDate = d3.time.format("%d-%b-%y").parse;

  // Set the ranges
  var x = d3.time.scale().range([0, width]);
  var y = d3.scale.linear().range([height, 0]);

  // Define the axes
  var xAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(x)
    .orient("bottom").ticks(5);

  var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    .orient("left").ticks(5);

  // Define the line
  var valueline = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function (d) {
      return x(d.date);
    })
    .y(function (d) {
      return y(d.close);
    });

  // Adds the svg canvas
  var svg = d3.select("body")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform",
    "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
  //EDIT ********************************************
  var line;

  // Get the data
  d3.csv("data.csv", function (error, data) {
    data.forEach(function (d) {
      d.date = parseDate(d.date);
      d.close = +d.close;
    });
    var entryData = data.map(function (d) {
      return ({date: d.date, close: 0})
    })

    // Scale the range of the data
    x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
      return d.date;
    }));
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
      return d.close;
    })]);

    //Bind the data first THEN add the valueline path.
    //Start with all zero y values
    line = svg.selectAll("line").data([entryData]);
    line.enter().append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", valueline);
    // Transition initial data, y values only
    line.data([data]);
    line.transition().delay(500).call(trans, "entry")
      // Add the valueline path.
      .attr("d", valueline);

    // Add the X Axis
    svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

    // Add the Y Axis with entry transition
    var gYaxis = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis");
    //Null axis starting point
    y.domain([0, 0]);
    gYaxis.call(yAxis);
    //Final axis after entry transition
    y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
      return d.close;
    })]);
    gYaxis.transition().delay(500).call(trans, "entry")
      .call(yAxis);

  });

  // ** Update data section (Called from the onclick)
  function updateData() {

    // Get the data again
    d3.csv("data-alt.csv", function (error, data) {
      data.forEach(function (d) {
        d.date = parseDate(d.date);
        d.close = +d.close;
      });

      // Scale the range of the data again
      x.domain(d3.extent(data, function (d) {
        return d.date;
      }));
      y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function (d) {
        return d.close;
      })]);

      //EDIT ********************************************
      // Bind the new data and then transition
      line = svg.selectAll(".line").data([data]);
      line.enter().append("path")
        .attr("class", "line")
      line.transition().call(trans)
        // Add the valueline path.
        .attr("d", valueline);

      // Select the section we want to apply our changes to
      var svgTrans = d3.select("body").transition();

      // Make the changes
      svgTrans.select(".x.axis") // change the x axis
        .call(trans)
        .call(xAxis);
      svgTrans.select(".y.axis") // change the y axis
        .call(trans)
        .call(yAxis);

    });
  }
  function trans (transition, name){
    var delays = {normal:0, entry: 500};
    name = name || "normal";
    transition.duration(750).delay(delays[name]).ease("sin-in-out")
  }
```